# BOT DirectLine integration with MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bots, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I created my BOT framework - LUIS. Hosted and tested too for the simple scenarios.
Now, I want to integrate that in my Registration portal which is based on the MVC framework,
I opted for DirectLine API to have more control on the BOT channel. But I am have a confusion in which method to use for:

1) https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat - Client side integration using React and supported css

2) https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLineWebSockets - C# to initialize the conversation in C#

Is there any advantage of using one over the other. Being a C# developer I opt for the second option But option one gives you the CSS/JS as well. I guess that we can more control if we chose option two but i am not confident though since i am new to BOT.

Please advise !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webchat is a component using DirectLine, it is a prepackaged integration that you can easily embed in your site.
It contains a webchat that has all the logic to communicate and handle the different types of messages. It also has pre built functionalities for speech.

DirectLine sockets is different: it's 1 (or more) layer down, it should be used if you are not interested in the UI of the webchat.